# PDO SELECT * if id and password then DISPLAY record

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Converting all my PHP to PDO.  Have a form that sends contractor_id and passwd.  Then searches database, if found it displays selected fields in that record.  Should be very simple, but either i'm missing something, or I have a type-o I cant see.  Thanks in advance for any help.

```
<html >
 <body>
<form action="display.php" method="POST" >
<input name="contractor_id" type="text" />
<input name="passwd" type="text" />
<input name="submit" type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
</body>
</html>



<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "searchdb";
$password = "passwd";
$dbname = "dbn";


try {
     $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=$dbname", $username, $password);
     $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
     $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT contractor_id, firstname, lastname, address, city, state, zip, email, areacode, phonenumber, ssnumber,
     rate, mykey, passwd FROM contractor_keys"); 
     $stmt->execute();


     $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM contractor_keys WHERE contractor_id=:contractor_id and passwd=:passwd");
     $stmt->bindValue(1, $contractor_id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
     $stmt->bindValue(2, $firstname, PDO::PARAM_STR);
     $stmt->bindValue(3, $lastname, PDO::PARAM_STR);
     $stmt->bindValue(4, $address, PDO::PARAM_STR);
     $stmt->bindValue(5, $city, PDO::PARAM_STR);
     $stmt->bindValue(6, $state, PDO::PARAM_STR);
     $stmt->bindValue(7, $zip, PDO::PARAM_STR);
     $stmt->bindValue(8, $email, PDO::PARAM_STR);
     $stmt->bindValue(9, $areacode, PDO::PARAM_STR);
     $stmt->bindValue(10, $phonenumber, PDO::PARAM_STR);
     $stmt->bindValue(11, $ssnumber, PDO::PARAM_STR);
     $stmt->bindValue(12, $rate, PDO::PARAM_STR);
     $stmt->bindValue(13, $mykey, PDO::PARAM_STR);
     $stmt->bindValue(14, $passwd, PDO::PARAM_STR);
     $stmt->execute();

     $row = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
     echo $row['firstname'].' '.$row['lastname'].' '.$row['address'] .' '.$row['city'].' '.$row['state']
     .' '.$row['zip'].' '.$row['areacode'].' '.$row['phonenumber'].' '.$row['ssnumber'].' '.$row['rate']
     .' '.$row['mykey'].' '.$row['passwd'];



catch(PDOException $e) {
echo "Error: " . $e->getMessage();
}
$conn = null;

?>
```

Comment: What is your problem ?

Comment: You have two placeholders, `:contractor_id` and `:passwd` - but you bind 14 values? I don't think you understand what [`bindValue();`](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindvalue.php) does?

Comment: Sorry, I left that part out.  When I run it, I just get a white screen with no results, and no errors

Comment: A white screen indicates a fatal error. Check your logs. And see [`error_reporting(E_ALL);`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php)
[`ini_set('display_errors', 1);`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ini-set.php)

Comment: Instead of all those `bindValue()` you just need `$stmt->execute(array("contractor_id" => $_POST['contractor_id'], "passwd" => $_POST['passwd']));` - you also have two queries, the first one doesn't even fetch anything and is being overwritten, so it's sort of redundant.

Comment: I guess I don't then, I thought if the two place holders are true then bind the values to the stmt for viewing

Comment: the first statement returns a recordset that is unused. also, close the statement `$stmt->free_result()` prior to the 2nd prepare statement. It looks like you are trying to use results from the first query as parameters for the 2nd query but you do nothing with the initial recordset. You need to associate the records with variables prior to the 2nd statement.

Comment: so now I have the following, still white screen and no errors in the log

Comment: $stmt->execute(array("contractor_id" => $_POST['contractor_id'], "passwd" => $_POST['passwd'])); 
         $stmt->execute();
         $row = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
         echo $row['firstname'].' '.$row['lastname'].' '.$row['address'] .' '.$row['city'].' '.$row['state']

Answer (score 0):

You could do away with the first query altogether and do something more like this:

```
<?php

    $servername = "localhost";
    $username = "searchdb";
    $password = "passwd";
    $dbname = "dbn";


    try {

         $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=$dbname", $username, $password);
         $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);


        $params=array(
            ':contractor_id'    =>  $_POST['contractor_id'],
            ':passwd'           =>  $_POST['passwd']
        );

         $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM contractor_keys WHERE contractor_id=:contractor_id and passwd=:passwd");
         $stmt->execute( $params );

         $row = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
         echo $row['firstname'].' '.$row['lastname'].' '.$row['address'] .' '.$row['city'].' '.$row['state']
         .' '.$row['zip'].' '.$row['areacode'].' '.$row['phonenumber'].' '.$row['ssnumber'].' '.$row['rate']
         .' '.$row['mykey'].' '.$row['passwd'];
      /*
          or perhaps even
          echo implode( ' ', $row );
      */



    catch(PDOException $e) {
        echo "Error: " . $e->getMessage();
    }
    $conn = null;

?>
```

---

As an example, the following is tailored to one of the dbs I have on my local machine but it works OK and closely follows above code.

```
    $dsn = 'mysql:dbname=stores;host=127.0.0.1';
    $user = 'xxx';
    $password = 'xxx';

    try {

        $customer='Alease.Gunderman'; /* static instead of POST var for testing */

        $db = new PDO($dsn, $user, $password);
        $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

        $sql='select * from customers where cust_name=:cust_name;';
        $stmt=$db->prepare( $sql );
        $stmt->execute(
            array(
                ':cust_name'    =>  $customer
            )
        );
        $row = $stmt->fetchAll( PDO::FETCH_ASSOC );
        echo '<pre>',print_r($row,true),'</pre>';

    } catch (PDOException $e) {
        echo 'Connection failed: ' . $e->getMessage();
    }
```

output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 6
            [cust_name] => Alease.Gunderman
        )

)
```

It seems likely that if you are unale to run a simple test example with your original code that the code lies elsewhere perhaps - maybe an included file?

Comment: I also verified my DB is working.  The following displays the whole table:try {
    $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=$dbname", $username, $password);
    $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT contractor_id, firstname, lastname, address, city, state, zip, email, areacode, phonenumber, ssnumber,
    rate, mykey FROM contractor_keys"); 
    $stmt->execute();
while($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
   echo "<tr>";
   foreach($row as $value) {
      echo "<td>{$value}&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp</td>";

Comment: Tried all the above and still stuck.  Get white screen with no errors and no error log either.  Just want to input an ID and a PASSWORD and have it display that record from my database.  Should be easy for a pro, but I'm a beginner.  I have it working in my none PDO but need to convert please.

Comment: If you get a white screen, @RickyT, it means there *are* errors. Did you enable error-reporting and check the logs?

Comment: Maybe I'm on the wrong site.  I am really trying hard to understand this stuff.  But my question has already been voted down and my question still doesn't work.  I feel like an idiot, but i'm trying, I mean this with all due respect to everyone, but I thought that's what you folks were here for.  Qirel, I don't know if it's enabled or not.  I do see an old error log file on my hosting site, but is dated from last February with old data in it.  Is this site to advanced for me, as I don't want to waste your time?

Comment: been having dinner: obviously the above is not tested so I need to rely upon you and your accurate reporting of issues. If I might I would suggest putting in a simple `exit('ok');` statement at various points to see if you can identify where things are going a little Pete Tong.

Comment: something weird is going on, placing exit('ok'); in various spots and not showing ok anywhere.  still trying to track it down

Comment: have to close php script ?> right after defining database variables, then place exit('ok'); then it says ok.  That's not right, closing everything down and re-booting

Comment: Ok RamRaider, placed the exit('ok'); right above the php ?> closing tag and got OK.  I have quadrupled checked the spelling of my variables.  Just get white screen and no errors

Comment: I would like to thank everyone for their input and help, but none of it really completely answered my question.  I have figured it out myself after 15 hours.  I would like to give everyone involved credit as well, it helped me learn, and also be persistent until I figured it out.  But can anyone tell me why my ? was voted down.  I thought it was a great question, for me and any new user in the future.  Was it the question, or the way I presented it?  I want to do things proper as stackoverflow is an awesome resource.  What should I have done different to get a thumbs up for my question?